# Dynamically load menu with ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a menu with sub menu and if you hover on one of the mainlinks, you will basically see its sub menu.
home
about us
services
contact us
where about us have sub menu like

```
1.what we do.
  1.1.link1
   1.1.1.link11
   1.1.2.link12
1.2.link2
2.why we are.
```

Ii am able to load data dynamically with Ajax up to fist level...
but could not for others sub sub menu.
I want to load sub menu with Ajax...
can any one help...
even I [google](http://google.com) it but fail to get my query ans.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because new level haven't listeners for hover action.
You should set listeners after getting data

You can use next scheme:

1. Every item of menu(`<a>` tag) have rel attribute
2. On hover you check, if level where uploaded
3. If data no loaded, send ajax query and send value of rel attribute
4. Display gotten data and set listeners for new items

Comment: suppose i hover on link12 and it diplay its sub menu and what about link12 level others menu...they will disappear when i hover on link12... it haved passed id to retrive data from mysql..."select * from table_name where parentid=$id" ...